# jQuery html() wont overwrite current html

Tags: jquery, html

Ok this is my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('href')
}).done(function( msg ) {
    $(this).parent().closest('p').html('Image Removed');
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <? foreach($galleryImages as $image) { ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $image['id'] ?>" class="box">
            <img src="<?php echo $fileHandler->get_thumb(__LISTING_GALLERY__.$image['image']) ?>" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image" /><br />
            <p class="text-right"><a href="<?php echo __BASE_URL__.'/installers/dash/delete_gallery.php?id='.$image['id'] ?>" class="confirmation"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</a></p>
        </div>
    <? } ?>
</div>
```

The ajax works fine since the database changes and such.
However, the done function isn't working properly.

I alerted the `$(this).parent().closest('p').html()` and it will alert the current html that div has. However, it won't overwrite it with the 'Image Removed' I'm typing in.

Comment: What does the alert tell you about the content? When does it occur? Beware that the done function is asynchroneous and might therefore be called after your alert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` inside the done function isn't the element, as there is a new function scope

```
var elem = this;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('href')
}).done(function( msg ) { // new function scope, "this" is now the XHR function
    $(elem).parent().closest('p').html('Image Removed');
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! =) I never knew that!

Comment: Now wondering, is context option working inside deferred method as done()?

Comment: @A.Wolff - yes, it should set the context for those methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax context option:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    context:this
}).done(function( msg ) {
    $(this).parent().closest('p').html('Image Removed');
});
```